# Cast Rails range to Postgres range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, range

I would like to know if it's possible to force Rails to cast ranges to postgres range when finding rows in DB
I have a table in my db with daterange column type

```
 create_table "events", force: true do |t|
   ......
    t.daterange "date"

  end
```

Rails knows how to cast range when I insert new rows
E.g

```
Event.create date: Date.today..Date.tomorrow
```

works as expected and I get a new row in 'events' table with date value equal to '[2014-07-16,2014-07-17)'

But when I try to select rows from db Rails casts range using to_formatted(:db) method
So

```
range = Date.today..Date.tomorrow
Event.find_by date:range
```

turns into

```
SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE ("events"."date" BETWEEN 2014-07-16 AND 2014-07-17) LIMIT 1
```

And what I expect to get is

```
SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE ("events"."date" [2014-07-16, 2014-07-17) LIMIT 1
```

I've extended the core Range class by adding new formatter to RANGE_FORMATS

And now use

```
Event.find_by date:range.to_s(:pg)
```

Is there more efficient way solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is now a 2 year old question, but I ran into a similar problem and figured I'd share my workaround.

I had a scope defined as such in an `ActiveRecord` model:

```
scope :score_range, ->(score_range) {
    where('course_placement_rubrics.score_range @> numrange(?)', score_range)
}
```

I called this scope like so:

```
CoursePlacementRubric.score_range( (0..5.0)  )
```

`ActiveRecord` built the following query:

```
SELECT "course_placement_rubrics".*
FROM "course_placement_rubrics"
WHERE (course_placement_rubrics.score_range @> numrange(0,1,2,3,4,5))
```

ActiveRecord tries to be helpful and iterates my range. In your case, ActiveRecord tries to be helpful and use the `BETWEEN..AND` predicate. That's obviously not what I and you want.

Here's my simple workaround:

```
scope :score_range, ->(score_range) {
    where('course_placement_rubrics.score_range @> numrange(?, ?)', score_range.first, score_range.last)
}
```

This outputs the query I want:

```
SELECT "course_placement_rubrics".*
FROM "course_placement_rubrics"
WHERE (course_placement_rubrics.score_range @> numrange(0, 5))
```

Hopes this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavior of AR. If you see in AR source:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L112

This is going to Arel `in` method:

https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/predications.rb#L27

So if you want to have prettier code, you need to override this `in` method.

Comment: I mean i want to find records which have the same range not the records that have the range including given value